# Which mail address to use in git repositories when contributing open source in Bitbucket?

Tags: email, bitbucket

I fear getting lots of junk when using my main address on Bitbucket.
 On github one can use username@users.noreply.github.com.

I was not able to find something similar on Bitbucket.

Could I simply invent username@noreply.com ?

Comment: I can't say I've noticed any extra spam from using my real address (but gmail's filters are quite good, too, so perhaps it's just getting caught and I'm not seeing the impact).

Comment: For me, Bitbucket only sends email when someone pushes to a repository I'm a part of. No emails besides those notifications.

Comment: @putty174 I wonder which mail to use in the repository's gitconfig not in Bitbucket.

Comment: You can use any address as long as it follows an email format. It will be visible to other contributors, but as for emails from Bitbucket, they will only notify you when other people push.